# If $A \subseteq B$, There Exists a Bijective Function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to show that if $A \subseteq B$ then there exists a function $f$: $A \rightarrow B$ that's injective.

I'm not sure how to start here. My knee-jerk reaction is to just give the definition of each (e.g., $\forall y(y\in a \rightarrow y \in x)$ and $\forall xy (x\ne y \rightarrow f (x) \ne f(y)$.) However, I'm not sure how this helps me.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: $$f (x)=x $$ a canonic injection.

Comment: I could have swear that this question was posted sometime in the last couple of weeks.

Comment: "∀y(y∈a→y∈x)[sic] and ∀xy(x≠y→f(x)≠f(y)"  Hint:  You also know as a tautology that $\forall xy(x\ne y \to x\ne y)$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: can you think of a way to take an element of $A$, and turn it into an element of $B$? Try to do this *in the easiest way possible* ...

Answer (score 1):

You can take the identity function $f(x)=x$.  It is injective from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: How did you come to think of that function?

Comment: @Adam It's the easiest way to take an element of $A$ and turn it into an element of $B$: realize that it *already is*, and then ... done! (Well, we have to check that it's injective, but it clearly is.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity function.  For $a \in A$, define  $f(a) = a$.   For distinct $a_1, a_2 \in A$, $f(a_1) \neq f(a_2)$ because $f(a_1) = a_1$ and $f(a_2) = a_2$.

Comment: I'm still not understanding the reasoning, and I'm struggling with doing a Fitch-style proof. Do you have any tips on how to going out proving this conditional claim with a Fitch-style natural deduction?